# Как изменить текст кнопки в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Я хотел сделать игру крестики нолики, в которой при клике на кнопку её текст попеременно менялся на **x** или **o**. Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")
root.title("Крестики нолики")
root["bg"] = "black"

def x():
    print("z")

def o():
    pass

b1 = Button(text="", command = x())
b1.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=100)
b2 = Button(text="")
b2.place(x=100, y=0, width=100, height=100)
b3 = Button(text="")
b3.place(x=200, y=0, width=100, height=100)
b4 = Button(text="")
b4.place(x=0, y=100, width=100, height=100)
b5 = Button(text="")
b5.place(x=100, y=100, width=100, height=100)
b6 = Button(text="")
b6.place(x=200, y=100, width=100, height=100)
b7 = Button(text="")
b7.place(x=0, y=200, width=100, height=100)
b8 = Button(text="")
b8.place(x=100, y=200, width=100, height=100)
b9 = Button(text="")
b9.place(x=200, y=200, width=100, height=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы заменить текст кнопки button на "New text." можно воспользоваться этим:

```
button.configure(text="New text.")
```

Далее просто после того как игрок нажимает на кнопку получаешь символ, который хранится в клетке и на основании символа вызываешь соответствующий метод.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать переменную с типом **StringVar** и передать её в конструктор кнопки указав ключ **textvariable**. В дальнейшем текст можно менять вызовом метода **set**:

```py
btn_text = StringVar(value="x")
next_is_cross = False

def update_btn_text():
    global next_is_cross
    btn_text.set("x" if next_is_cross else "o")
    next_is_cross = not next_is_cross

    
btn = Button(textvariable=btn_text, command=update_btn_text)
```